# createEntity with breeze and enum value

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, enums, breeze

I've created an app with angular and breeze and use an Enum (State) property in almost all of my classes. Now I want to create an entity with breeze but getting an error on the "State" property. Is there a way that i can use the Enum-type throughout my whole angular/breeze app? How should i address/call the Enum-type?

---

```
 function createProductManufacturer(productId, manufacturerId) {
        return this.manager.createEntity(model.entityNames.productManufacturer,
            {
                ProductId: productId,
                ManufacturerId: manufacturerId,
                State: State.Changed // here is the problem...
            });
  }
```

---

```
public class ProductManufacturer
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}


public enum State
{
    Normal = 0,
    Changed = 1,
    Deleted = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done so far will only expose one `Enum` `State` Name corresponded to one entity `ProductManufacturer`. i.e. when executing Entity Query against `ProductManufacturer`, you'll get each `ProductManufacturer` entity accompanied with one single `State` Name.

if you want to send the `enum` `state` values, you need to expose them as a lookup object.

In your `BreezeController`, Add an `HTTPGET` Method and include your `enum` values:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
        var  States = Enum.GetNames(typeof(State));// This is how you expose Enum values 
        var  Countries = _contextProvider.Context.Countries; // This one is a database lookup table
       return new {States, Countries  };
     }
```

Then you can query against your lookups using typical breeze's `EntityQuery` (Do that on application start.)

Comment: Thx Adel, I didn't look at this approach. This will solve my question